# rvm upgrade error with 'command gem pristine --extensions debugger --version 1.6.0 failed'

Tags: ruby, rvm

I'm getting this error when upgrading ruby with rvm:

```
Error running '__rvm_with ruby-2.1.5 gemset_pristine',
showing last 15 lines of /Users/snowcrash/.rvm/log/1419348453/gemset.pristine-ruby-2.1.5.log
+ gem pristine --extensions yard --version 0.8.6.2
+ read _gem _version _platforms
+ ((  1 > 0  ))
+ rvm_error '\n'\''command gem pristine --extensions debugger --version 1.6.0'\'' failed, you need to fix this gems manually.'
+ rvm_pretty_print stderr
+ case "${rvm_pretty_print_flag:=auto}" in
+ case "${TERM:-dumb}" in
+ case "$1" in
+ [[ -t 2 ]]
+ return 1
+ printf %b '\n'\''command gem pristine --extensions debugger --version 1.6.0'\'' failed, you need to fix this gems manually.\n'

'command gem pristine --extensions debugger --version 1.6.0' failed, you need to fix this gems manually.
+ return 1
```

Any suggestions on how to fix?

Answer (score -1):

The debugger gem is not compatible with ruby 2.1.5. Perhaps you have it listed as one of you default gems, that you install for every ruby. If you remove that bit of configuration you should be good to go.

Have a look at you ~/.rvm/gemsets/global.gems

Comment: This contains: gem-wrappers,
rubygems-bundler,
bundler,
rake,
rvm (I'm using a "," instead of a newline as newlines aren't allowed in comments).

Comment: In that case its probably another gemset that is causing the problem. You could have a look at the existing gemsets for the ruby you are upgrading. A better approach might be to install a new ruby, rather than upgrade an existing one. You can investigate what rvm is trying to do by running `gem help pristine`. You can find out more about the ruby you are trying to upgrade with `rvm info`